# Facebook API Raitngs endpoint returs no data about reviewer

Tags: facebook, api

i am trying get all reviews from my Facebook Page. I would like get all reviews with author´s name and author´s profile picture, but "reviewer" returns **no data** - see this screen - https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH7Wu.jpg

I am using page access token with this permissions:

- pages_show_list
- pages_manage_metadata
- pages_read_user_content
- public_profile

So is any chance to get all reviews from my Facebook Page with reviewer´s name and profile picture? Pls how?

I tried something like this, but it does not work :-(

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/PAGE-ID?access_token=TOKEN&fields=ratings.fields(reviewer{id,name,languages,picture.width(120).height(120)},created_time,rating,recommendation_type,review_text,open_graph_story{id,message,type,data{is_hidden,language}}).limit(20),overall_star_rating,rating_count
```

Comment: Is your app still in dev mode? You will need to take it live, before you can expect this kind of access to user data to work.

Comment: yes, it is still in dev mode. OK, i will try to publish it. Thx

Comment: If i switch my app to live mode, there is a error message "Page Public Metadata Access requires either app secret proof or an app token"

Do i need "Page Public Metadata Access" permission for this? Because Facebook rejected my request for this permission.

Comment: You likely don’t have a valid page access token now. You will have to submit for review and get the permissions approved first.

Comment: I am very confused - pls can you help me? I switched my app to live mode (https://prnt.sc/tqh5dt).

Then I requested 2 permissions (pages_read_user_content and pages_read_engagement) - https://prnt.sc/tqh68l

Now I am getting page access token from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ - see https://i.imgur.com/gkDnWZu.jpg

But i get error message.. Pls can you help with this procedure?

Comment: That does not look like the review was actually completely already. There should be _green_ dots for permissions you actually got approved, not yellow ones with “Complete Verification” next to them.

Comment: If i use app token i will get this error: https://i.imgur.com/9P3he3H.jpg, but i already have "pages_read_engagement" - https://prnt.sc/tqh68l

:-(

Comment: ok, so I'll try to ask for approval again. thx

Comment: Wow, I had to confirm Supplemental Terms Contract and now is my app live ;) thx!